# What does curl --data-binary map to in Invoke-WebRequest in powershell?

Tags: powershell, curl, powershell-2.0

What does `curl --data-binary` map to in `Invoke-WebRequest` in powershell ?

```
Curl "http://mysiteURL" -u user:pass --data-binary "input=1&type=3"
```

I tried:

```
Invoke-webRequest -Uri "http://mysiteURL" -Credentials $MyCreds -Body "input=1&type=3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the people at Microsoft decided that powershell should do this sort of "hijacking". You can avoid it by invoking curl as "curl.exe".

See also [Removing the PowerShell curl alias](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/08/19/removing-the-powershell-curl-alias/)

Comment: I'm not sure this answered their question, which would appear to have been "What does `--data-binary` map to in Invoke-WebRequest?". I have the same question and am coming to the conclusion that using `curl.exe` is the only way.

Comment: I offered a working work-around as I knew about one. It's not like a lot of other answers got drowned...

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but I ran into this today in the context of sending success signal to [AWS CloudFormation WaitConditionHandle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-waitconditionhandle.html) and spent several hours figuring out the equivalent syntax of passing a `--data-binary` in curl to what would work in PowerShell with `Invoke-WebRequest` method. Putting this answer in case it helps people who come looking for something similar.

This is the starting curl command that I was building an equivalent for:

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type:' \
 --data-binary '{"Status" : "SUCCESS","Reason" : "Configuration Complete","UniqueId" : "ID1234","Data" : "Application has completed configuration."}' \
 "<WaitConditionHandleURL>"
```

The equivalent in PowerShell is:

```
$Headers = @{ "Content-Type" = ""}
$Data_Str = '{"Status" : "SUCCESS","Reason" : "Configuration Complete","UniqueId" : "ID1234","Data" : "Application has completed configuration."}'
$Data_Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($Data_Str)
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Wait_Handle_URL -Method Put -Headers $Headers -Body $Data_Bytes
```

The thing that took me the most time to figure out was that the string needed to be encoded and sent as bytes. In my case ASCII encoding worked, it is possible that other encoding, e.g., UTF8 maybe needed for other applications.

Answer (score 0):

For binary data from a file (e.g. an image) you can do:

```
$Headers = @{
    'Content-Type' = 'image/tiff'
    'Filename' = 'test.tiff'
}

$img_path = "/path/to-image/test.tiff"
$Image_Bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($img_path)
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $API_URL -Method Post -Headers $Headers -Body $Image_Bytes
```

which is equivalent to `curl`'s:

```
curl -s -X POST $API_URL -H "Content-Type: image/tiff" -H "Filename: test.tiff" --data-binary "@/path/to-image/test.tiff"
```